# Inject parameters and an object into pipeline processor using DI

Tags: configuration, dependency-injection

How do I pass a parameter to the processor's constructor AND resolve its dependencies?
In the config I have:

```
<processor type="Feature.ErrorHandling.Pipeline.HttpRequest.PageNotFoundProcessor, Feature.ErrorHandling"
                   resolve="true"
                   patch:before="processor[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.ExecuteRequest, Sitecore.Kernel']">          
 <param desc="excludeSiteNames">SHELL|ADMIN|LOGIN|SERVICE|MODULES_SHELL|MODULES_WEBSITE</param>            
</processor>
```

the constructor:

```
public PageNotFoundProcessor(IErrorPageRepository errorPageRepository, string excludeSiteNames)
{
      _errorPageRepository = errorPageRepository;
      _excludeSiteNames = excludeSiteNames;
}
```

I receive the following error:
`Unable to resolve service for type 'System.String' while attempting to activate 'Feature.ErrorHandling.Pipeline.HttpRequest.PageNotFoundProcessor'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add a public variable with the parameter name and also modify the constructor to only accept the object that needs resolved:

```
public string ExcludeSiteNames { get; set; }
public PageNotFoundProcessor(IErrorPageRepository errorPageRepository)
{
    _errorPageRepository = errorPageRepository;
}
```

In the config file, modify it like the following: (note: the pipes were causing it to not map correctly, but commas worked fine)

```
<processor type="Feature.ErrorHandling.Pipeline.HttpRequest.PageNotFoundProcessor, Feature.ErrorHandling" resolve="true"                   
patch:before="processor[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.ExecuteRequest, Sitecore.Kernel']">
<ExcludeSiteNames>SHELL,ADMIN,LOGIN,SERVICE,MODULES_SHELL,MODULES_WEBSITE</ExcludeSiteNames>
```